# How to assign value to property class when giving a object as parameter?

Tags: c#

Sorry if the title does not reflect what I actually want.

I'm creating a generic class for selecting, updating, inserting and deleting dates from and to a database.

Basically, I want a function that gives me back an ObservableCollection<"can be anything"> ==> Where anything is a class and not strings. I would like to know if it is possible to do this, if yes, please,help me how I can achieve this.

this is my starting point:

//class a

```
    public static ObservableCollection<ContactPerson> contactPersons = new ObservableCollection<ContactPerson>();

    public static ObservableCollection<ContactPerson> getContactPerson()
    {
        contactPersons = (ObservableCollection<ContactPerson>)DBConnection.GetDataOutDatabase(typeof(ContactPerson), "Contactpersoon");

        return contactPersons;
    }
```

//class b

```
        public static Object GetDataOutDatabase(Type myType,String table)
    {            
        ObservableCollection<Object> objecten = new ObservableCollection<Object>();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        DbDataReader reader = Database.GetData(sql);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            objecten.Add(Create(myType, reader));
        }

        return objecten;
    }

    private static Object Create(Type myType, IDataRecord record)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = (PropertyInfo)myPropertyInfo[i];
            String name = myPropInfo.Name;
            Type type = myPropInfo.PropertyType;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this is what I ultimately want to get. Is this possible?

```
        //ContactPerson cp = new ContactPerson();
        //cp.ID = (record["ID"].ToString());
        //cp.Name = record["Name"].ToString();
        //cp.Company = record["Company"].ToString();
        //cp.JobTitle = new ContactPersonTitle()
        //{
        //    Name = record["JobTitle"].ToString(),
        //};
        //cp.JobRole = new ContactPersonType()
        //{
        //    Name = record["JobRole"].ToString(),
        //};
        //cp.City = record["City"].ToString();
        //cp.Email = record["Email"].ToString();
        //cp.Phone = record["Phone"].ToString();
        //cp.Cellphone = record["Cellphone"].ToString();
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with reflection in generic methods.

```
public class DBConnection
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> GetDataOutDatabase<T>(string table)
    {
        var objecten = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        DbDataReader reader = Database.GetData(sql);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            objecten.Add(Create<T>(reader));
        }
        return objecten;
    }

    public static T Create<T>(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var returnVal = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        properties.ToList().ForEach(item =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (item.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        item.SetValue(returnVal, Convert.ChangeType(record[item.Name].ToString(), item.PropertyType),null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object[] parameters = {record};
                        var value =
                        typeof(DBConnection).GetMethod("Create").MakeGenericMethod(item.PropertyType).Invoke(null, parameters);
                        item.SetValue(returnVal,value,null);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Write("Property Not Found");
                }
            });
        return (T)returnVal;
    }
}
```

The example above does assume that all properties names match the column names you are retrieving from your database communication.  For instance in the ContactPersonTitle above rather than Name you would need to have JobTitle as the property name.

Comment: i tried this code and it crashes on this part
properties.ToList().ForEach(item =>

the var properties, i get all the properties and returnVal set every value on null

Comment: i think the problem lies in the fact i have 2 more properties i don't want to use for this function. i tried to remove some properties form var properties, but there isn't a .remove function for it. can it be this is the problem so yes how can i remove a index from var properties if it is equal to a type i specify?

Comment: in this case personally I would wrap the if statement in a try catch block inside the properties.tolist linq expression, if you don't want to swallow the exception i would suggest simply logging it.  This would allow the properties you are using to be set, and the properties you are not would remain null, rather than trying to exclude properties from the list

Comment: also the reason there is not a .remove function is because Type.GetProperties returns an array.

Comment: still not solving the problem, thanks anyway, i'm a lot farther then i was before

Answer (score 0):

Not as you are currently doing it. You should look into the entity framework which allows translation of database tables datacollections.

have a look at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B

Comment: not exactly what i wanted, basically i need to find a way to cast object to a parameter given by different class. from that casted object, i need access to his properties to assign values or get his values. but thanks anyway